# Javascript event triggers

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm trying to create an Ajax enabled webform, and have created a simple page. On the page, I have a div that contains the value I wish to edit.

I've got working javascript to add a text input box around the contents of the div, complete with a Save button to post back to the web server, but unlike the [example](http://24ways.org/2005/edit-in-place-with-ajax) I'm following, I don't want a cancel button, instead I want the cancel operation to be triggered by the input box losing focus.

I've added a onblur event to the text input box to cancel the edit operation and return the form back to it's original unedited state (and not save the change).

The problem I'm having, is that when I click the 'Save' button, the onblur event of the text input box is also triggered. How can I stop this happening?

The edit function (called when a user clicks on the text to be edited) is as follows:

```
function edit(obj)
{
  Element.hide(obj);
  var textarea = '<div id="'+obj.id+'_editor"><div class="fieldvalueedit"><input type="text" id="'+obj.id+'_edit" name="'+obj.id+'" rows="1" size="64" value="'+obj.innerHTML+'"></div>';
  var button = '<div class="fieldvaluebuttons"><input id="'+obj.id+'_save" type="button" value="Save"/></div></div>';

  new Insertion.After(obj, textarea+button);
  document.getElementById(obj.id+'_edit').focus();
  Event.observe(obj.id+'_save', 'click', function(){saveChanges(obj)}, false);
  Event.observe(obj.id+'_edit', 'blur', function(){cleanUp(obj)}, false);
}
```

Comment: Well you can't stop it, because the element will inevitably lose focus when you click on something else. What might work would be to wrap your "blur" activity in a timeout that runs a few milliseconds after the actual blur. Then you can use a handler on the submit button to set a flag, which the blur handler would check.

Comment: Looks like the [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org) JavaScript framework. I believe that the [prototypejs] tag is more useful than, say, `web-development`.

Comment: @RobW It is indeed prototype.js, I've updated the tags to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: -1 for Rob's comment... i spent five minutes looking at the code, and wasn't getting it

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez, apologies, I've never used Javascript (and hence Prototype.js before, so I don't profess to know which bits where Javascript and which bits where Prototype.js. I didn't realise it was relevant TBH, but I've added the tag as suggested.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you don't want an explicit cancel button? It sounds like if I accidentally hit Tab or click outside the editor, I'm going to lose all my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an onblur event on input you can register an onclick event on the document that resets the textareas state, then cancel the propagation of this event when the save button is clicked (you will want to apply this to the text area as well).

```
Event.observe(obj.id+'_save', 'click', function( e ){
    e.stopPropagation();
    saveChanges(obj);
}, false);
Event.observe(document, 'click', function(){cleanUp(obj)}, false);
```